# Multiview calling button click event when in not active view

Tags: asp.net

I have a multiview with two views. view at index 0 is "Readonly" and view at index 1 is edit view. by default is is set to show reaonly view with this :

```
<asp:MultiView ID="mv" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
```

I click a button I enter some information in view 1 and click save and it goes to view 0 with this code:

```
protected void SaveLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Page.IsValid)
   {
      bool success = Save();

      if (success)
      {
         LoadViewMode();
         mv.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
      }                    
   }
}
```

Now after clicking save button, when I am in reaonly view. If I refresh the button, It calls save function again. I don't know why ?

Please suggest solution to it.

Comment: how do you "refresh the button"?

Comment: what do you mean by `if I refresh the button`? maybe you meant page?

Comment: using broswer refresh button

Comment: yes sorry i mean refresh page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you refresh the page (not the button), the last request that returned the page being viewed is resubmitted to the server. Therefore, the server executes the same code again.

Comment: lgor how to get rid of this ?

Comment: I tried this Ifmv.ActiveViewIndex == 1) in save function but index is 1 even though i changed it to 0 after save

Comment: Get rid of what? This is the standard browser behavior.

Comment: I want that when page is refreshed then save function is not called because this is adding records in db with each refresh

Comment: Then you need to keep some information server-side (possibly in `Session`) and check it to see if `Save` needs to be executed. Another way is to do `Response.Redirect` after setting `mv.ActiveViewIndex = 0;` to get a non-postback page again. Consider what you are going to do when user uses the `Back` browser button.